# Java API: How to insert an array vector into a DolphinDB table with MultiThreadedTableWriter?

Tags: java, arrays, dolphindb

I have tried to insert a Java’s `int` array into a DolphinDB table using the following script:

```
new BasicIntVector(
new int[]{quote.getAskVolume1(), quote.getAskVolume2(), quote.getAskVolume3(),
                  quote.getAskVolume4(), quote.getAskVolume5()})
```

However, an error was reported: `Failed to insert data. Cannot convert Entity to DT_DOUBLE_ARRAY`. How can I modify the script?

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by the mismatch between the Java’s primitive data type `int` and DolphinDB's `Entity` class. So you need to replace the `int` type with the corresponding wrapper class `Integer`:

```
new BasicIntVector(
        new Integer[]{quote.getAskVolume1(), quote.getAskVolume2(), quote.getAskVolume3(),
                  quote.getAskVolume4(), quote.getAskVolume5()})
```